# yq, adding single quotes on json values

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq, yq

I have a shell variable with the following JSON string:

```bash
echo "${user_part}"

{
  "exec": {
    "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "args": [
      "-c",
      "'sops --decrypt ${tokens_file} | jq -cM ''{\"kind\": \"ExecCredential\", \"apiVersion\": \"client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1\", \"spec\": {}, \"status\" : {\"token\":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}'''"
    ],
    "command": "bash",
    "env": [
      {
        "name": "context",
        "value": "utility"
      },
      {
        "name": "tokens_file",
        "value": "\"/home/some-user/.kube/tokens with space in name.enc.json\""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After yq is applied I've got this:

```bash
echo "${user_part}" | yq --prettyPrint

exec:
  apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
  args:
    - -c
    - '''sops --decrypt ${tokens_file} | jq -cM ''''{"kind": "ExecCredential", "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1", "spec": {}, "status" : {"token":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}'''''''
  command: bash
  env:
    - name: context
      value: utility
    - name: tokens_file
      value: '"/home/some-user/.kube/tokens with space in name.enc.json"'
```

Desired result:

```yaml
exec:
  apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
  args:
    - -c
    - 'sops --decrypt ${tokens_file} | jq -cM ''{"kind": "ExecCredential", "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1", "spec": {}, "status" : {"token":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}'''
  command: bash
  env:
    - name: context
      value: utility
    - name: tokens_file
      value: "/home/some-user/.kube/tokens with space in name.enc.json"
```

So, values are passed as is without single quotes added in these:

- `.exec.args[1]`
- `.exec.env[1].value`

Exactly to content in json.

How to switch off this single quote escaping entirely, without specifying custom conversion on specific elements by yq?

Removing escaped double quotes in the second case leaving the string completely unquoted by YQ:

`"value": "/home/some-user/.kube/tokens with space in name.enc.json"` => `value: /home/some-user/.kube/tokens with space in name.enc.json` in YAML. Which is not what is needed

---

Added based on comments:

This all is part of "synthetic" kubectl config file.

I've had first version manually crafted:

```json
users:
  - name: utility
    user:
      exec:
        apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
        args: ["-c", "sops --decrypt ${tokens_file} | jq -cM '{\"kind\": \"ExecCredential\", \"apiVersion\": \"client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1\", \"spec\": {}, \"status\" : {\"token\":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}'"]
        command: bash
        env:
          - name: context
            value: "utility"
          - name: tokens_file
            value: "/home/some-user/.kube/tokens with space in name.enc.json"
```

Which worked fine, and so is a fragment in "desired" section

What is in the original, single-quoted example, is kubectl-updated fragment once I changed the context or namespace (Kubernetes). And is what kubectl reprocessed yaml file is

I presumed this single-quoted version, produced and consumable by kubectl is more appealing, hence no inner json quote escaping in inner single quotes. But as you said, might not be by-the-book

While multi-quoted, "past-yq" errors out:

```bash
kubectl get namespace
bash: line 1: sops --decrypt ${tokens_file} | jq -cM {"kind": "ExecCredential", "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1", "spec": {}, "status" : {"token":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}: No such file or directory
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable bash failed with exit code 127
```

Removing quotes to "desired" state makes it working, so I used it as success criteria

Comment: You shouldn't have the extra quotes in your input JSON to begin with. `["bash", "-c", "'command1 | command2 ...'"]` generates an invalid argument vector; it's not a legitimate bash command with the inner single quotes. _In your proposed YAML_ the triple quotes are fine when used as syntactic quotes that don't require further escaping in the contents, but trying to transform bad input to good output is a route that one generally should avoid trying to go down in the first place.

Comment: You are asking yq to represent a JSON-encoded string in YAML encoding. Nothing is being altered. It's the same content in a different encoding. Try `echo "${user_part}" | yq --prettyPrint | yq -o json` and you'll see that you will get back the same original input.

Comment: Also, _all JSON is valid YAML_, so if you fix your JSON input, you won't _need_ to do any conversion at all: a YAML parser will just accept the JSON as-is.

Comment: Thank you,

I've added a comment, editing the original question. I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The problems here go well beyond conversion to YAML: The original input JSON document is itself broken.

If you fix that, you'll be able to use it directly, without needing any conversion at all, because all valid JSON is also valid YAML; and you'll *also* ensure that the output of any conversion to conventionally-formatted YAML is identical in meaning (if not choice of syntax) to the document you actually want.

- When you double up single quotes in bash (in either an unquoted context or a single-quoted context), they cancel each other out; `''foo''` in bash is exactly the same as `foo`.
- When you put single quotes at the front and end of your argument passed as `-c`, you're specifying to the shell that the entire command is one word (aka the name of an executable). That's clearly not true, and it's going to cause a `command not found` error.
- When you expand `$tokens_file` without *syntactic* quotes around the expansion (to be syntactic, the quotes need to be in the shell-language source code, **not in the variable's value!**), that variable is word-split into separate values.
- Your environment variable has *literal* quotes in the value of your .kube token, but only *syntactic* quotes are appropriate there. When you add literal quotes, the software is looking for a filename with `"` characters **in the name itself**.

A corrected version of your document might look like:

```json
{
  "exec": {
    "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "args": [
      "-c",
      "sops --decrypt \"${tokens_file}\" | jq -cM '{\"kind\": \"ExecCredential\", \"apiVersion\": \"client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1\", \"spec\": {}, \"status\" : {\"token\":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}'"
    ],
    "command": "bash",
    "env": [
      {
        "name": "context",
        "value": "utility"
      },
      {
        "name": "tokens_file",
        "value": "/home/some-user/.kube/tokens with space in name.enc.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think, your answer is good, but doesn't work for Kubectl generate. Might be, it is non-standard. And my question is not correct hence the issue is with Kubeconfig or Golang yaml, IDK:

if I pass this json to var via heredoc, I ended up to have:

`- 'sops --decrypt "${tokens_file}" | jq -cM ''{"kind": "ExecCredential", "apiVersion": "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1", "spec": {}, "status" : {"token":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}'''`

Comment: While kubectl works with this (manually corrected):

`- "sops --decrypt \"${tokens_file}\" | jq -cM '{\"kind\": \"ExecCredential\", \"apiVersion\": \"client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1\", \"spec\": {}, \"status\" : {\"token\":.tokens[$ENV.context]}}'"`

Double quote around, no single quote duplication

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the change between what's in the answer and what's in the comment immediately above, but feel free to edit the answer yourself -- it's flagged community wiki, which means I've disclaimed personal ownership of it.